# command not found in shell script

Tags: shell-script, variable

Please tell me why I couldn't print variable value.

```
# chmod 777 chkscript.sh
# ./chkscript.sh
```

**chkscript.sh** file content

```
variable = "This is variable"

echo "$variable"

echo "Hello World "
```

**Output :**

```
# ./chkscript.sh
./chkscript.sh: line 5: variable: command not found

Hello World
#
```

**P.S :**
And sometimes

```
 variable1 = "/home/files" --- which is location if I try to print nothing gets printed.
 echo "$variable"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In shell, spaces are not allowed on either side of the `=` in a variable assignment.

Try this instead:

```
variable="This is a variable"
```

If you leave a space before the `=`, the shell parses the token before it as a command or function name, which is why you see the "command not found" message.

Comment: variable="This is variable"

echo"$variable"

changed like this but no use.Thanks for reply.

Comment: You still need the space after `echo` - if you omit it, the shell expands what's in `$variable` and then tries to find the command that is called (in this example) `echoThis` with the arguments `is variable`. Almost certainly NOT what you want!

Comment: Thanks for the insight on that. I am still learning shell scripting as I go :)

Comment: Finally fixed this Thanks you.It is really hard to fix space related thing here.Thanks for all your replys.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, and I did this:

```
#!/bin/sh
my_chars='This is test' ;
echo $my_chars
~
```

#### Now

```
$ ./test_chars.sh
This is test
```

#### This works

Comment: This doesn't really explain what was wrong.